# CMake not wanting to link with libGL.so

Tags: opengl, cmake, kdevelop

I was coding in KDevelop, ant I set up my CMakeLists.txt to include and link against libGL and freeglut.

However, it gave me the following error:
`make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/libGL.so', needed by 'opengl'.  Stop.`

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(opengl)
add_executable(opengl main.cpp)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}  ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries(opengl ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} )
```

Comment: Just chiming in, that on occasion I get the same error, but I never was able to figure out what causes it. It usually resolves by deleting the build directory and doing a fresh `cmake ${SOURCE_TREE}`.

Comment: How do you do that? I'm new to cmake.

Comment: By the way, libGL.so is in order, but has *many* symlinks

Comment: The usual way to work is to create a build directory outside of the source tree, `cd` to it and generate the makefiles from the source tree using cmake. For example `mkdir /tmp/builddir ; cd /tmp/builddir ; cmake /…/projectdir`

Answer (score 0):

First, what I am about to suggest might depend on CMake version, but I don't think (I'm using cmake version 3.1.0).

Looking at the installed FindOpenGL.cmake file, it looks like the variable you want in target_link_libraries is ${OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY}. Case does matter.

The best way to test an issue like this one is to use message("var: ${var}"), then you would be able to clearly see what your variable is set to during configuration.

Hope this helps!

FYI, I found the find module in the ${cmake_install_dir}/Modules/Find* where cmake_install_dir=/usr/share/cmake on my linux machine.

EDIT**
Sorry, was tired this morning and missed that you wanted GLUT, not GLU. There is a FindGLUT.cmake Module. You should call find_package(GLUT REQUIRED) and use ${GLUT_LIBRARIES} and ${GLUT_INCLUDE_DIR}. Sorry about the confusion!